# how to show excel pivot filter pop up in excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot

I want to be able to show the excel pivot filter pop up for a specified column in the table through VBA

the pop up filter is the thing with "Sort A to Z", and all your values / search box etc.

any ideas if this is possible?

thanks
Dom

Answer (score 0):

There's a few pivot dialogs. Here's the wizard.

xlDialogPivotTableWizard

From Help

```
dlgAnswer = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show
```